# Python Pandas: value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame - Solution?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried every solution that I found about this problem without success. I have a dataframe composed of columns: Timestamp, Bid. Then I add these columns:

```py
df["Close"] = df["Bid"]
df["Open"] = df["Bid"].shift(price_frame) 
df["High"] = df["Bid"].rolling(window=price_frame).max() 
df["Low"] = df["Bid"].rolling(window=price_frame).min()
```

And then, when I do the following operation I receive error:

```py
df['Open - Close'] = (df['Open'] - df['Close']).abs()
df['Upper Wick'] = (df['High'] - df[['Open', 'Close']].max(axis=1)).abs()
df['Lower Wick'] = (df[['Open', 'Close']].min(axis=1) - df['Low']).abs()

df['Bias'] = np.where(df['Open'] > df['Close'], 'Bearish', np.where(df['Close'] > df['Open'], 'Bullish', 'Doji'))
```

Here's what I get after executing code above (however the code calculation works and seems to be good):

```
/var/folders/ml/x1xlmr8s617fg971yk8310x80000gn/T/ipykernel_49689/2146060031.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['Open - Close'] = (df['Open'] - df['Close']).abs()
/var/folders/ml/x1xlmr8s617fg971yk8310x80000gn/T/ipykernel_49689/2146060031.py:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['Upper Wick'] = (df['High'] - df[['Open', 'Close']].max(axis=1)).abs()
/var/folders/ml/x1xlmr8s617fg971yk8310x80000gn/T/ipykernel_49689/2146060031.py:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['Lower Wick'] = (df[['Open', 'Close']].min(axis=1) - df['Low']).abs()
/var/folders/ml/x1xlmr8s617fg971yk8310x80000gn/T/ipykernel_49689/2146060031.py:5: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['Bias'] = np.where(df['Open'] > df['Close'], 'Bearish', np.where(df['Close'] > df['Open'], 'Bullish', 'Doji'))
```

Thank's

Edit: the thread to which this one is called "duplicate" does not answer the question relative to my situation.